# Malformed entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list

Tags: apt, updates, sudo

After running `sudo apt update` I am getting the following error:

```
E:Malformed entry 3 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list([option]) not assignment)
E:The list of the sources could not be read.
```

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm  *Xenial is Ubuntu 16.04*

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that your sources can not be read because you have a bad entry in line three of the file at `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list`.  You need to remove or comment this line, or delete this `.list` file.

You didn't tell us what version of Ubuntu you are using but please be aware that community support has ended for Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial).